# how to get hold of object from other classes in appDelegate when app enters background

Tags: ios, appdelegate

I got a class which runs a bunch of timers, and when the app enters background I want to stop them. I know of course this is done in the appDelegate but when I got the `timer` class initialized  as an instance variable in another class.. What´s the common ways of getting hold of the instance object in the appDelegate?

Do I delegate the `didEnterBackground` to the class with the timer i want to stop?

Do I make the timer a singelton?

Use the notification center?

or, hopefully there are better ways than this!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest thing to do here is [post a notification](http://zeroheroblog.com/ios/notifications-in-ios-part-1-broadcasting-events-via-nsnotificationcenter) when your app delegate gets the "`didEnterBackground:`" call.  And have your timer class (or class that has a bunch of timers) listening for that notification.

You'd need an matching app-delegate-does-a-post method if you want to restart the timers when the app comes back to the fireground.

Comment: Ok! I guess Having the ViewController recieve the notification would be the easiest, cause then I can update the GUI accordingly.

Comment: The easiest.. but can be easily abused. I'm not sure if this is a safest way. And definetely results that application will be harder to debugging in background behavior.

Comment: Okay. Let's roll with this @SimpleMan:  if Tom's timer class receives a notification that the app is going into the background and the method called by the notification checks to make certain all the timers are not nil and return "`YES`" for ["`isValid`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/isValid), how else would a crash happen from a notification?

Comment: Notification break natural object-oriented flow in code. The "Normal" way is an object call object/method. Notification jump to completely different class. There are usuful in your parent class (for example in `UIManagedDocument` and wrapper class for it). But using NSNotification to jump to completely different place in your code is bad design.

Comment: A notification sends a message to all observers that something has happened. If your app has one run loop, the observer methods will all run in order* and then you'll return back to the place where the notification was posted from. And hopefully those methods return quickly, especially if the app has entered the background -- one only has an extremely short time to get everything done before the app is suspended. This is *almost* the same concept as a delegate method (which is 1-to-1 notification), only here a NSNotification can tell any (1 or multiple) observers that something is happening.

Comment: I am not argue with that. But delegates can be easily abused either! This is easy, clean way to communicate with method without creating an object, I'm aware of it, but this break natural flow as i said before. Delegates have one, huge advantage - an object send it! So you now where you can find receiver, declared protocol and properties. With NSNotification you only send name, with is NSString! This is crude, error causing solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're right - the only method you will need is `didEnterBackground` method in your appDelegate.

Using notification center may cause you a lot of problem (you 100% positive that every time app enter backgound you will have timers fire in your class?). Notification Center in this case can easily cause crash.

Here is what i will do:

1. Set up my timers in one class (let's call it `TimerManager`)
2. Make my class a Singleton class.
3. In `TimerManager` i will create array/set with timers.
4. Call singleton class right after my first ViewControllers will load (or in AppDelegate). Basically right after my app will start.
5. Add `Timers` to my Set/Array when i need it.
6. Create a method `stopAllTimers`

\

```
-(void)stopAllTimers {

  for(NSTimer *timer in self.allTimers) {
   [timer invalidate];
  }
}
```

1. Call this method in my `didEnterBacground` : `[[TimerManager sharedInstance] stopAllTimers]`

That's it and this is perfectly safe.

Comment: Q:(you 100% positive that every time app enter backgound you will have timers fire in your class?) A: I only want to stop the timers when it enters the background (if they are running, they might not), But I can check this in the class that recievies the notification. great answer btw!

Comment: Right, if they not, you probably call notifiation and app will crash with `unrecognized selector:` error.

Comment: If i just call the viewController that uses the model, then I can handle the case if the model is not initiallized there. I think this is the right way to do it.

Comment: ViewController? Not sure. I will go with Singleton. Remember your view controller can not exist. When you call [TimerManager sharedInstance] even if not exist yet will be initialized. You may modify `stopAllTimers` adding in first line `if(!self.allTimers) return;` and that prevent iterate in not allocated array.